# Comparing a constant array with object array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a collection of objects with certain attributes.
I also have a CONSTANT array of ids.

I want to return the whole objects who have an id that exists in the constant array.

This is what I have so far, but it just returns true or false for each, I need it to return an array of all the objects:

```
some_object_attributes.collect { |attr| (Constant::SOME_IDS.include? attr.object.object_type_id)}
```

How can I return every `attr.object` which has an ID in the constant array?

Comment: How many ids are there in the constant? What is the size of the object array? Using a `Set` instead of an array might improve the performance a lot.

Comment: Is there a reason this cannot be a query parameter? something like `scope :in_constant_array, -> { where( object_type_id: Constant::SOME_IDS)}` then you can leverage SQL to do the lifting rather than in mem

Comment: There is only a dozen or so IDs in the constant..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to do a `collect` (aka `map`), which returns the result of the block. You want to return the object in the collection based on the result of the block. For that, there's [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
some_object_attributes.select do |attr| 
  Constant::SOME_IDS.include? attr.object.object_type_id
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just out of curiosity, for a really huge array that way it might be faster:

```
some_object_attributes.group_by do |attr|
  attr.object.object_type_id
end.values_at(*Constant::SOME_IDS).flatten
```

This is `O(N)` because it does not look up the `Constant::SOME_IDS` array for each element.

Comment: I suck at algorithmic complexity, but doesn't `values_at` do a similar thing behind the scenes, iterating and matching? It's surely faster than doing so in Ruby, but still affects your cost.

Comment: @coreyward it looks up the hash, it is promised to be O(1).

Comment: Ohhh that's right because the hash lookup table is divided by bitwise hashing and the full table isn't scanned. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Use `select` instead of `collect`.

`collect` is returning the result of the evaluation (`true` or `false`). `select` will return the objects.

This [article](http://jacopretorius.net/2012/01/ruby-map-collect-and-select.html) may be of use.